# Calculate two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a little help with two sheets in Excel:

Sheet1

```
id    name      in stock
1      test     44
2      test2    55(become 50)
3      test3    66
```

Sheet2

```
id  name   ordered
2   test2  5
```

End: when I enter `5` in Sheet2 (`ordered`) automatically subtract from Sheet1 (`in stock`) for id `2` and name `test2`. I use LOOKUP for id and name, when I enter `2` in id automatically show name `test2`. But I need help with subtracting. I know I need to use SUMIF but no sure how.

Comment: You could use three sheets: `Starting values`, `Orders`, `Current values`

Comment: You are trying to subtract an order received from stock in hand, however the subtraction should only take place after the order has been prepared and invoiced, I suggest to create two additional columns to hold the quantities ordered and the available stock.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly said in your post, you may use SUMIF.

Let's consider that on the two sheets, "id" is always in column A, "name" always in column B, and "in stock" and "ordered" always in column C. You can calculate the actual stock of the third row, where id "2", in cell C3 as follows

```
=55-SUMIF(Sheet2!A:A,A3,Sheet2!C:C)
```

As expected result is 50. This approach by the way is not very convenient, because you should add the formula manually in every row of your table on Sheet1. As suggested above by others, it would be better to have at least another column where you put the starting values of the stock, so that you can replace the actual stock in figures with a reference to the relevant cell.